# How to call SOAP method?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I create simple web application use [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-java-web-application-integration-example/). So, I have `HelloWorld` class:

```
package test;
@WebService
public class HelloWorld{

@WebMethod(operationName="getHelloWorld")
public String getHelloWorld( String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
}
}
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
  name="HelloWorldWs"
  implementation="test.HelloWorld"
  url-pattern="/hello"/>
</endpoints>
```

And web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

So, how to call `getHelloWorld` method, if I run this application on tomcat?

Comment: Did you deploy it to tomcat yet?

Comment: Go to the base URL of your service and append "/servlet-name"

Comment: It depends on you what client you are looking for. If it is a java client you are asking, there is one implementation. If you want to test it from SOAP UI etc,. you have to use the end point.

Comment: However, remember a web service is NOT necessarily an accessible web site that you can load in a browser.

Comment: @JNYRanger Ok. So how to setting endpoint for calling method?

Comment: @user3629171 Sorry I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: @JNYRanger Sory. I want to see "Hello, Ann" at browser. For this, I should call `getHelloWorld`. How to do this?

Comment: See my other comment.  Web Service != Web Site.  You need to either create a client to interact with the web service or use another service to communicate with it.  See @KostyaBut 's link in the comment of the answer below:  http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-to-call-web-service-from-browser.  You may want to read up a bit on how to consume Web Services.

Answer (score -1):

Just create an object to the class and call the method using that object, just as you do for other classes.

```
HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
obj.getHelloWorld("test");
```

Comment: No. How to call this method from `url` ?

Comment: Explanation here: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-to-call-web-service-from-browser